# ignore files with Trino DB on AWS S3 with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, aws-glue-data-catalog, trino

I got TrinoDB with a AWS Glue Hive Store on a S3 Bucket with the following Structure:

```
root
|-folder1
  |-folder2
    |- file1.csv.gz
    |- metafile.json
```

I created a table with a crawler and add ignore pattern for any JSON file. Table Structure is create correct, But when I Query the Table in TrinoDB I get the contents of the json file not from the CVS's.
Trino Connector conf looks like that:

```
hive.metastore=glue
hive.hide-delta-lake-tables=true
hive.s3.path-style-access=true
hive.metastore.glue.region=eu-central-1
...
```

Any Ideas how to ignore the json file in Trino

Comment: Can you share the Glue crawler configuration? Specifically, the exclude patterns.

Comment: @AndrewNguonly **.json, the schema was created correct based on the csv.

Comment: I also tried `**/metafile.json` and a lot of other exclude pattern, all with the same result. In `Crawler Excluding : aws-splunk-bills-ssc/ssc-billing/ssc-testreport/20220301-20220401/ssc-testreport-Manifest.json. Matches pattern: aws-splunk-bills-ssc/ssc-billing/ssc-testreport/**/ssc-testreport-Manifest.json.`the pattern works but in Trino and in Athena I get the content of the JSON files instead of the csv's.

Comment: This Stack Overflow question/answer may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125762/excluded-folder-in-glue-crawler-throws-hive-bad-data-error-in-athena/72128424#72128424

Comment: @AndrewNguonly sounds like the same. thx Strange that AWS exports its own Data (Account Costs) in a format that Athena could not read.